# Tomcat configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: tomcat, ssl, configuration, intellij-idea, datasource

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.2 and I have already configured tomcat instance (context.xml, server.xml, keystores, other properties files). I want to configure idea to use this tomcat server with all that settings (datasources, ssl connector) but I can't find how to do that in "Run/Debug Configurations" -> "Tomcat Server". Does anyone know how to do this "right" way without editing idea's files?

**UPDATED:**

Here is example of tomcat configuration in idea 11. Where could I point to use my custom server.xml, context.xml and other conf files? It doesn't use that files which are in %tomcat_home%/conf.
[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and Tomcat.. Howto..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041356/intellij-and-tomcat-howto)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi you should do these steps:

Add you tomcat server "Setting" -> "Application Servers" -> "Add" -> "Tomcat Server"
Then you setup your tomcat installation path. If you have your setting (datasources, ssl connector) in differend tomcat base you can set it there too. Here is example of configuration.
[image: Tomcat configuration]

Setup you runner "Run/Debug Configurations" -> "Add New Configuration" -> "Tomcat Server" -> "Local" and in "Application Server" combobox select your Tomcat.

Is it ok this description for you?

Comment: Hi chalimartines! Thanks for response. You wrote "If you have your setting (datasources, ssl connector) in differend tomcat base you can set it there too", could you clarify where I can set it? I added UI screenshot and there are no possibility to setup custom configuration files.

Comment: Tomcat home is path where you have all binary files for tomcat and your configuration for first instance (server.xml etc.). Tomcat base is directory where you can have another server instance and contains only configuration files (server.xml etc.). Here you can find more information about tomcat instances http://kief.com/running-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server.html

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't clear for me about tomcat base directory.

Comment: Look out for errant carriage returns in server.xml if you use other tools that rewrite entries to it (such as eclipse)