# How to deploy tomcat/webapps folder from IntellijIDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7, wicket, wicket-1.5

I am testing a web application (Apache Wicket Based) via Intellij IDEA Tomcat integration. There I noticed that the webapp consider its running in bin folder of the tomcat. Also when I called the `ServletContext.getContext("/")` it returns `null`. But when I deploy the same webapp manually in tomcat it works fine. How can solve this in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and Tomcat.. Howto..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041356/intellij-and-tomcat-howto)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's try.

1) Create IntellijIdea project via WebApplication template. Idea should be Ultimate version, not Community edition

[image]

2) Go to Run-Edit configutaion and set up Tomcat location folder, so Idea will know about your tomcat server
[image]

3) Go to Deployment tab and select Artifact. Apply 
[image]

4) In src folder put your servlet (you can try my example for testing purpose)
[image]

5) Go to web.xml file and link your's servlet like this

[image]

6) In web folder put your's .jsp files (for example hey.jsp)

[image]

7) Now you can start you app via IntellijIdea. Run(Shift+F10) and enjoy your app in browser:

**- to jsp files:** http://localhost:8080/hey.jsp (or index.jsp by default)

**- to servlets via virtual link you set in web.xml :** http://localhost:8080/st

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ (I'm using Ultimate 2017), the context directory is set through File > Project Structure. Under the Web Resource Directories list, IntelliJ had filled in a path ending with `/webapp` by default, which didn't exist and was in red. I changed that to the folder enclosing my root-level `index.jsp`. After a rebuild, my JSPs were rendering and the CSS and JS (stored in the same tree as the JSPs) were loading perfectly.

[image: Project Structure dialog, with incorrect directory]