# Cannot run/debug jsp page from within IntelliJ using Tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I created a new project and created artifact for it.
When I run Tomcat from command prompt and go to: `http://localhost:8080/IntelProject1/index.jsp`

I can see my page.

But when I try to run it from IntelliJ, it opens empty page: 
    http://localhost:8080

and if I try to go to:
`http://localhost:8080/IntelProject1/index.jsp`

this is what it displays:

`HTTP Status 404 - /IntelProject1/index.jsp`

```
type Status report

message /IntelProject1/index.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
```

The reason it is able to find it from tomcat is because I edited server.xml file in tomcat/conf folder:

```
<Context path="/IntelProject1" docBase="C:\Users\ibogojevic\Desktop\IntelProject1\web\JSP" />
```

But I want to be able to open it and debug from within `IntelliJ`

Maybe my artifact is wrong.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Check step-by-step settings like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551130/hot-to-deploy-tomcat-webapps-folder-form-intellijidea/30255771#30255771

Comment: i consider this unresolved. there is no suitable answer yet the answers don't work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open **Debug Configuration** in IntelliJ IDEA and make sure that **Deploy applications configured in Tomcat** checkbox is checked as it shown on the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: does not do it. it must be something else.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked with:

> File >Project Structure >Artifacts

In the

> Output Layout on the right side >"Available Elements?"

right click on the *available libraries* ( for me it was "Spring MVC-4.2.4.RELEASE")

> Put into Lib

And it worked.

Comment: that does not help the slightest bit.

Comment: I do not have Put into Lib anywhere :F

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.