# How to create Spring MVC application with Maven structure in Intellij IDEA 13.1?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I want to to create new **Spring MVC** project in **Maven** structure using **Intellij IDEA** but can't do that. actually i want to create project like **[mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com)** samples, like [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/).

**NOTE**

I'm new to **Intellij IDEA** and want to create new project not import from existing project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need to do is the following.

Click `File` -> `New Project` and then:

First add [this](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) Maven archetype (from the button on top right)

[image]

That archetype will help you bootstrap the project by providing some Spring configuration code and must be present in your local Maven repository (directions are provided on how to do that in the link I sent - it's very easy).

After adding the archetype just do like in the following screenshot:

[image]

The next screen just asks you for the the `GroupId`, `ArtifactId` and `Version` of your project. The following screens are trivial.

That's it!

Note that you can use any archetype you like (although the one I supplied seems to be very much up to date). If you find a better one than the one I supplied, feel free to use it. You can also write your own without too much trouble.

Comment: After completing these steps, IntelliJ complains about unmapped configuration files.  I could resolve that error, but there are further problems, so I may not have resolved it correctly.

Comment: Which configuration files are unmapped?

Comment: ApplicationConfig, JpaConfig, MongoConfig, SecurityConfig, and WebMvcConfig.

Comment: The unmapped files are not a problem when it comes to running the code. They are used by IntelliJ in order to provideSpring hints. What other kind of problems are you having?

Answer (score 7):

Update as per comment for IntelliJ **15**:

Same instructions apply and here's a view from it:

[image]

Also note that **Spring Initializr** has been added in the same **New Project** screen that is becoming the de-facto way of initialising **Spring Boot** applications.

---

*(initial post)*

In IntelliJ **13** Ultimate Edition it's very simple since the template is built-in:

`File` > `New Project` > `Spring` > `Create project from template` > `Spring MVC`

[image]
[image]

Comment: How to apply **Maven** structure to the project??

Comment: The built-in template is a Maven project.

Comment: Could you take an screenshot to me!

Comment: @dimitrisli how could this be done in IntelliJ 15 ultimate? Can't find it.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem updated the answer with extra details

Comment: @dimitrisli Thanks for the quick answer! But the problem is, if I do that, there is no template generated with the hello world. There is also no "webapp" folder and no pages folder that has the views. Isn't there a possibility to make a new project with the same hello world template in IDEA 15? There is also no Maven.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem try to use Spring Initializr project. It can do what you want.

Comment: You won't get a `pom.xml` file using this approach. Go with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The above suggestions didn't work for me.
What I did is [Creating MVC project](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype#create-a-project) straight up with Maven, based on the `archtype`:

> http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype

The command is:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.codeleak \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
    -DgroupId=my.groupid \
    -DartifactId=my-artifactId \
    -Dversion=version \
    -DarchetypeRepository=http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype
```

Or, if you want to just Copy-Paste it to `shell` or `cmd` in one line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.codeleak -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=my.groupid -DartifactId=my-artifactId -Dversion=version -DarchetypeRepository=http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype
```

When `DgroupId`, `DartifactId` & `Dversion` are the `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` of your project.

It will generate a full working maven project.

The next step is just to import the maven project to IntellijIDEA.

As for **Version 14.1.4:**

1. `File` -> `New` -> `Project from Existing Sources...` and choose the Project you generated.
2. Check the `Import project from external model` and choose `Maven`.
3. At this point there will be more configurations, but you can just click `Next` & `Finish`.

To run the project in your browser you would need to install and configure [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).

[IntelliJ and Tomcat.. Howto..?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4041356/3501205)

Comment: I am seeing this error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (pl.codeleak:spring-mvc-quickstart:1.0.0) -> [Help 1]

Comment: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.codeleak -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=5.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myArtifact -Dversion=version -DarchetypeRepository=http://kolorobot.github.io/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype worked for me. I changed architypeVersion to 5.0.0