# Maven archetype for Spring MVC in IntelliJ

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, maven-3

Is there a maven archetype for Spring MVC to use from IntelliJ or a tutorial to create a Spring MVC webapp using IntelliJ instead of using it's own Spring MVC template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Spring MVC application with Maven structure in Intelij IDEA 13.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678794/how-to-create-spring-mvc-application-with-maven-structure-in-intelij-idea-13-1)