# Why tomcat is not running the Spring MVC web application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I get started with a simple web application using the Spring framework and when I trying to run in the `IntelliJ`, the BUILD is successfull but the app is not getting started, like you see the `red` lines tell you usually. I get the message provided below:

[image]

I have the following `web.xml` file,

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file is as following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="rest.mvc"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And, here is my project structure:

[image]

This is the code for the test controller:

```
package rest.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by Chaklader on 9/23/16.
 */

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){

        return  "view";
    }
}
```

What is the issue here and how to solve it?

Note:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>basic-web-app</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-web-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON Processing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: skipping - non-war project

Comment: You said you were getting a message; I don't see one. Additionally, if you're getting started with Spring, use Spring Boot; it makes all of that configuration unnecessary.

Comment: You may clarify the statement ?

Comment: Paste your pom file. check the packaging type for the project.

Comment: Here is what I get from the console : http://i.stack.imgur.com/U47Jm.png

Comment: Have you Configure the Application Server to tell IntelliJ where Tomcat is installed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041356/intellij-and-tomcat-howto

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below section for tomcat plugin in pom.xml and see if it works

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>     
    <configuration>
        <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```